# Image Loader, cannot connect to

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

This is what I have.

```
  ImageLoader imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance(); 
  imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mcontext));
  imageLoader.displayImage("http://sunflower-astronomy.com/KCKCC_Docs/LabImages/ngc4631.bmp",imageView)
```

I get error message below in Logcat.  My internet connection is working.  I heard you need to use asynctask for api greater than 11 for web connections.  Is that true? Does that apply here as well?

03-19 08:05:38.298: E/ImageLoader(5173): failed to connect to www.sunflower-astronomy.com/69.72.240.50 (port 80) after 5000ms

Comment: Did you set the privilege to your app, that it could use the Network?
Does it work with a local Image Resource?

Comment: i set it in my manifest yes, i haven't tried it with a local image resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above code is running in your UI thread, then you should use an AsyncTask, otherwise your UI will lock up while the image is being fetched.  That's not the cause of your problem though.

Your problem is that the file you're requesting is huge, and so the ImageLoader is timing out.

To increase your timeout, use something like: `.imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(5000, 30000)` on your ImageLoaderConfiguration.

That will give it 5 seconds to establish the connection, and 30 seconds to download it.

Comment: Actually, I might need to retract that.  It seems to be timing out on the connection part.

Comment: nope, you're right. it works with VERY small images on the current config, i underestimated the time it would take to download the image.

Comment: I'm glad I didn't delete my answer then!  That image you're downloading is 4MB, so will take a while even on a pretty good network connection.